# Delete a row from datatable that contains certain column value

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, datarow

I am trying to delete a row from datatable based on one of its column value

```
    String st = "ok";
    DataRow[] drr = dt.Select("Remarks=' " + st + " '");
    for (int i = 0; i < drr.Length; i++)
        drr[i].Delete();
```

It is not working, am I missing anything here?

Comment: maybe `dt.AcceptChanges();` at the end, going off this example [`DataRow.Delete`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow.delete?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Thanks, but I am using that.Actually this is working for Integer, but here I am trying to match a String

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely its the leading and trailing space in the select, try something like

```
dt.Select("Remarks='" + st + "'")
```

Also, you open yourself to a [SQL Injection Attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

If you want to persist with using strings, then the [new way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) is

```
dt.Select($"Remarks='{st}'")
```